# How could gender on 1st person pronouns come into existence?

Tags: culture, gender, conlang

How could gender on 1st person pronouns come into existence? I've been working on a language where every noun is required to state what gender it is. The 5 genders male, female, real, not-real/unknown, alive, and dead. For all my pronouns I wanted them to have it required as well. I've been trying to create the culture through the language and then edit the language by stuff I want in the culture. why would a culture have 1st person pronouns with gender required?

Comment: No idea but speaking Spanish, Romanian, Italian, Japanese, Portuguese and French is quite hard without affirming your gender. Looking into those languages' history could help.

Comment: There are many languages where each and every noun has a grammatical gender. For example, most European languages. There are also quite a few languages where (some) 1st person pronouns have grammatical gender; for example, in Spanish, *nosotros* means "we" (all male, or mixed sexes) and *nosotras* means "we" (all female); or in Latin, *meus*, *mea* and *meum* al mean "my" or "mine", depending on the grammatical gender of the possessed object. (And those five things of yours are nominal classes, not genders; first because there's five of them and second because they appear to be motivated.)

Comment: All in all, you are asking a question about a fantastic element which is actually an ordinary occurrence in the real world, which your diligent preliminary research should have revealed.

Comment: To put it succinctly, gender in language is always masculine, feminine, or neutral and doesn't change because of the actual biological sex (or lack their of) of the item in question (for example the Russian word for bear is masculine.  That does not mean there can't be female bears.  Just that the word for their species is feminine.).

Comment: Trough history there were all sorts of ways to adress oneself, and nothing strange in forms like zomby I, vampire I, us the emleror, doctor who. If u think it is too long to adress humble me user of wb, then you haven't seen archaic texts.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding MathCookie! Just as a piece of friendly advice: It is customary to wait a while before accepting an answer, usually at least 24 hours. This benefits you as more people are encouraged to answer which in turn gives you better answers, and also gives people who might live in time zones around the world a chance to have a go at answering as well.

Comment: @EdvinW sorry I will do that next time. thanks for telling me

Comment: Gender in language is not totally aligned with biological gender, as Mark Twain pointed out about German. "Where is the beautiful and accomplished English maiden? It has gone to the opera."

Comment: And your genders are overlapping: which one do you use if somebody is male, real, and alive?

Comment: @NomadMaker You choice which one is more important to the speaker or to the listener.  you can only do one or the other.

Comment: I'm wondering, how do you use the "dead" 1st pronoun? Is it only useable by skeletons, zombies and archlichs :p?

Comment: @Tortliena Yes well kind of. The dying and the spirits only uses it. though if you are dying and you use it and you don't die in the next 3 weeks you might be breaking some social rules.

Comment: @hszmv In Russian, most living beings have separate words for male and female beings. There is a special word for she-bear and it would be incorrect to use the he-bear word to talk about a bear that is known to be female. Russian also has common gender, e.g. words like teacher or monster. These nouns are used unchanged for both males and females, but the associated adjectives take on feminine or masculine endings depending on the gender of the actual being.

Comment: It becomes socially important for people to communicate whatvgender they are, and thus all pronouns divide into male and female (and possibly other) forms.

Comment: I believe Thai uses different first person pronouns depending on the gender of the speaker.  [From wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_language#Pronouns): ผม (RTGS: phom. IPA:pʰǒm) = I/me (masculine; formal), ดิฉัน (RTGS: dichan, IPA: dìʔt͡ɕʰán) = I/me (feminine; formal).  I know nothing about Thai though so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: For the real-world linguistics of this, see the [chapter on pronoun gender](https://wals.info/chapter/44) in the World Atlas of Language Structure (WALS), and its references.  From a few minutes of skimming, my impression is that languages with gendered first-persoun pronouns exist (e.g. Ngala, Korana shown in the linked chapter) but are really pretty rare.  Unfortunately WALS lumps together 1st- and 2nd-person pronouns in its summary numbers; it looks to me like most of “Gender distinctions in 3rd person plus 1st and/or 2nd person” is actually just in 2nd-person.

Comment: @Otkin:  My Russian never evolved past once playing with the Cyrillic.  I know a joke that uses the ordinary word's gender as part of the gag and relies on Bear being a masculine word and fox being a feminine word.  A similar but weirder issue occurs in German where "The Girl" is neutral but a specific girl will be referred to using feminine pronouns.

Comment: @nick012000 that is because dead is not a gender silly.

Comment: I couldn't help noticing that you list six categories, not five.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Gender" as a linguistic concept is a way that languages divide things into categories.  The common genders in real-world languages are "masculine," "feminine," and "neuter."  They are labeled thusly because they vaguely line up with the real-world concepts of "male," "female," and "neuter."

Vaguely.

For example:  In Spanish a group of all males or of mixed sexes would refer to themselves as "nosotros," while a group consisting of all females would use "nosotras."  The way that kind of pattern stays mostly consistent is where the names of the linguistic genders comes from.

On the other hand...

"la mesa" -- "the table" --  It's feminine...  Why?  Nobody knows.  It just got lumped into that category at some point and nobody's had a reason to move it.

Here's an example of a similar pattern in English that is not gender:

- Cattle -> Beef
- Sheep -> Mutton
- Pig -> Pork

If you've studied languages you may notice that the word for the living animal is the word for the animal from the anglo-saxon side and the word for the processed meat of the animal is the general word for the animal in French...

Probably because the animals were being raised mostly by the English-speaking peasants, and consumed mostly by the French-speaking nobility.

So there's a good set of options for how your language's pattern could arise.

1. Utility:  This is a set of categories that constitute everyday useful information (or did at some point in the past.)
2. Coincidence: Nobody was really paying that much attention and part of the pattern arose out of some quirk of the vocal apparatus making it easier to say in this way, or association with utility patterns that the words in question are commonly used near.
3. Collision:  Multiple languages melded into one, but some (probably cultural) division resulted in a distinctive pattern.

And this applies to the first-person pronouns as easily as the others.

Utility:  For some reason which category the speaker belongs to isn't always immediately obvious, but it's important information for the listener to know without having to ask.  Maybe a language which developed for use in a medium other than face-to-face?  That would pull in at least some of your categories.  Might even get all of them if everyone in your society is an arm-chair philosopher or poet and so would have any use at all for first-person-unreal and first-person-dead...

Coincidence:  You have a highly-regular language where all the pronoun categorization is extremely predictable.  There's such a solid pattern to all the other pronouns that children learning the language reflexively apply them to the first-person ones as well, even though some of those categories would be difficult to ever hear used in real life.

Collision:  You have a trade language born out of the melding of not just two different cultures, but two entirely different species which see the world in wildly different patterns.  There's enough overlap that they can still communicate and get along with each other, but first-person-masculine makes about as much sense to one group as first-person-unreal does to us.  That strange division would cause all kinds of weird ripples in the language, including possibly the necessity of gender agreement that would essentially make the speaker use one language's pronouns in combination with one set of words and the other language's pronouns with another set of words.

And remember the "vaguely" part.  You could easily end up with things like first-person-unreal being used to express disbelief.  So something like "I <first-person-masculine/feminine> was dancing on the tables last night." would be a statement of fact while "I <first-person-unreal/unknown> was dancing on the tables last night." would indicate that that's what you'd heard about yourself from others but you don't remember it yourself and aren't inclined to believe it.  And that goes back to the utility category of conveying useful information in as few words as possible.  Kind of like Navajo has a verb for dropping a round object and a verb for dropping a stick-like object.  Because apparently that was an important thing to differentiate at some point.

Thanks for the interesting intellectual exercise.  The one additional thing I'd point out is that languages tend to simplify themselves over time because people are lazy.  And having lots of different pronoun declensions is a pretty big chunk of complexity that's likely to get shed the instant that the categories cease to be meaningful to the speakers. (See the real-world shift away from strict use of formal vs informal declensions over the last couple centuries.)  So whatever specific reasons you come up with for why there are so many likely need to be ongoing or within the past few hundred years in order to be believable.  Or else there needs to be some additional factor holding the language stable.

Answer (score 28):

Japanese has already some first person pronouns which are only to be used by male.

The gender neutral is 私 (watashi), while 僕 (boku) can only be used by males, while 俺 (ore) is still male only, but quite more arrogant.

If it has happened for Japanese, it can happen to a greater extent for your language.

Incidentally there are also other constructs which are gender specific in Japanese: for example a man can say of some food that it is 美味しい (oishii) or  うめぇ (umee), while a woman would normally use only the first one.

Comment: "can only be used by males" is overstating it.  More like "usually used by males".   See [this](https://www.fluentu.com/blog/japanese/i-in-japanese/).  The Japanese gender rules for the 1st person pronoun are not as strict as the English rules for third person pronouns.

Comment: (Though obviously it is easy to see how a language like Japanese, with optionally gendered 1st person pronouns, could evolve into one that requires it.)

Comment: This answer would be strengthened if it addressed the two main questions in the OP: *Why* does Japanese have these different pronouns (what purpose do they serve for speakers of that language), and *how* did this system come into existence? I don't know if there are definitive answers, but surely there are some theories.

Comment: @DLosc: That's particularly important in the case of Japanese, because not all linguists even agree that those words are pronouns in the first place.

Comment: Japanese avoids most pronouns.  Usually people use names or titles instead of second or third person pronouns.

Comment: @GorttheRobot Japanese avoids pronouns talking to/about other people. Japanese is a high-context language, so often even first-person pronouns (e.g. 私) can be omitted if the topic is obvious in a given scenario (for example: 眠いです / [I] am tired). If it isn't obvious, etc. or the speaker wants to be clear, then first person pronouns will be used, or the topic will be introduced, etc.

Comment: _Incidentally there are also other constructs which are gender specific in Japanese_ - I would say it's much deeper than this.  Someone's whole way of speaking in Japanese can vary a lot depending on their gender/status, the addressee's gender/status and the relationship involved.  I would guess that the relationship-dependent language is at the root of how 1st personal pronouns became partially gendered (feminine speech uses softer words, etc.)  You also forgot the standard feminine one: atashi.

Answer (score 20):

One reason first person pronouns might be gendered is if it's difficult for others to tell the speaker's gender from available cues.

If, for instance, the language is similar to Earthly whale song, it's commonly used far beyond either vision or scent range; yet if one of its original functions was finding a mate, it would save everyone involved a whole bunch of annoyance if you can tell if the person you're hearing is a suitable mate.  Later (perhaps a number of speciations later), the language is being used "face to face" -- but it's still derived from "I need to tell you my gender because you can't see/smell me."

Comment: possible subversion - the language would still have a neuter gender, used for "I'm not interested in mating, but I still want to perform long-distance communication" ... and then it becomes customary to prefer it over gendered first person pronouns, because those insinuate the desire to mate... or at least pride

Answer (score 8):

By fusing previous "ungendered" pronouns with a separate word class. This happened in Spanish (albeit only in the plural), where the original 1st person plural *nos* fused with *otros* (masculine) or *otras* (feminine), yielding the modern *nosotros* (masc.), *nosotras* (fem.), by analogy with the 2nd person *vos* + *otros* that arose to distinguish the 2nd person plural from the 2nd person singular honorific *vos* (previously plural).  Note that Spanish has only two genders (more or less),  thus only two genders for the pronoun. Also note that despite the appearance, the pronoun is not exclusive.

Comment: +1 This is called increasing syntheticity and is very common in how languages develop.

Answer (score 5):

**Why have declensions in grammar?**

Harassed students might suspect that it is just to drive them mad, or to let the teachers assign more homework. Mark Twain said he'd heard someone say he'd rather decline two drinks than one German adjective.

If you look at that last sentence, you'll notice that I used "he'd" twice. The first time it refers to Mark Twain, the second time it refers to the unknown language student. The difference is made clear by the word order. But the second "he'd" might also have been referring to Mark Twain, who would in this case report what someone else said about him.

If it had been about Mark Twain and a female, then Mark Twain would have said he'd heard someone say se'd rather decline two drinks than one German adjective. The alternative interpretation becomes impossible. The gendered form **removes ambiguity** and serves as a kind of [checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum) or even [error-correcting code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_correction_code). Consider a sentence like "Alice saw it himself." It would be obvious that there was an error somewhere.

A language could develop which puts more emphasis on this kind of redundancy. A strong oral history tradition, and no writing?

Comment: The larger number of "genders" could be useful here.  You could use, for example, in your example about Mark Twain, the male pronoun for Mark Twain and the real pronoun for the language student (or perhaps the other way around, since Mark Twain definitely existed and the language student may not have!).  If the language has a convention that you don't use different pronouns about the same person in the same sentence, then that would make it unambiguous which is which.  (Of course, that's less likely to arise with 1st person pronouns, but still).

Comment: Should that female adjective be "she" and not "se"? Anyway, gendered pronouns make for a really limited error correction: they do nothing to error correct nouns and verbs, just disambiguate between two people, and only when they're of opposite genders. They do nothing to disambiguate between e.g. two brothers or same-gender friends. Though I suppose gossiping about heterosexual couples or would-be couples is a common enough use to warrant it...

Comment: If gendered pronouns come about from the need to reduce ambiguity, then I would think gendered first-person pronouns would be more useful in written language than spoken language, because the reader of a text cannot see the author to determine (or guess at) the author's gender.

Comment: "Consider a sentence like "Alice saw it himself." It would be obvious that there was an error somewhere." I think that transgender advocacy groups would probably disagree. ;)

Comment: @nick012000 or indeed Alice Cooper

Comment: @ilkkachu, genering pronouns is just one aspect of a declension-rich grammar.

Comment: I suspect that languages with weak word ordering rules would rely more on "matching" via declinations and other word tags.

Comment: @jk., where I live parents are required to pick a name of the right gender. Adults can make a non-traditional decision, parents can't inflict that on their children.

Comment: @o.m., um, yes? does that make them any better for error-correction?

Comment: @kaya3, it depends on the language. "I'm a musician" doesn't tell you anything about my gender. "Je suis musicienne" or "Ich bin eine Musikerin", on the hand, very much does, namely that the "I" who is speaking identifies as female.

Comment: @nick012000, when I read that, I immediately thought of "Alice saw himself in the mirror", as a hint about her fate after being struck by some sex-changing effect in a fantasy story...

Comment: @KeithMorrison All I'm saying is that gendered first person pronouns would be more useful for disambiguating in written language than in spoken language when the speaker is present; that's a comparative statement, I'm not saying gendered first person pronouns are useful or that they aren't useful. The same applies to third person pronouns; "they are a musician" doesn't tell you about gender while "they are a waitress" does (and is grammatically correct, stop complaining, lesser pedants).

Comment: Here's the actual quote, from Twain's "The Awful German Language" ( https://faculty.georgetown.edu/jod/texts/twain.german.html ): 

"I heard a Californian student in Heidelberg say, in one of his calmest moods, that he would rather decline two drinks than one German adjective. "

Comment: @Alan, I needed the double *he'd* to make my example work. I'll drop the supposedly.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, such 1st Person Personal Pronouns with gender can develop. These can develop in cultures which have a great focus on honorifics and taking into account the state of the speaker and the one spoken to.

Look at Japanese, it has various 1st Person Pronouns, 私 (*Watashi*) is slightly formal or feminine, 僕 (*Boku*) is youthful masculine, 俺 (*ore*) is a more forceful and arrogant male term, 手前 (*temae*) is gender neutral humble when used for onself, and so on.

These form, as mentioned previously, as being a sort of formality. If a language uses a great degree of honorifics, chances are it would have various forms of first and second person pronouns that depend upon speaker and the spoken to. But this is the case if you wish for it to develop in a language without grammatical gender, if it has grammatical gender, which is commonly used, it is not absurd for it to come to apply to pronouns of all persons. As seen in Spanish with their First-Person Plurals, *nosotros* and *nosotras*.

It is actually a pretty common feature in general, as other have mentioned above.

Even English used to have this to a degree with formal and informal second-person pronouns. You and Thou.

So yes, either

1. Just make a culture which used a great degree of honorifics
2. Simply having a language which marks words by gender in of itself if reason enough for this to be applied to pronouns as well.

Answer (score 4):

You ask how does this gender difference come about. If we look at the development of language from simple pidgin language to a creole, we see how a spoken language develops from simple to complex with a grammar and other structures. This all depends on the local needs. Words are invented, adapted, and stolen from other languages and then modified to communicate the situation. Language comes out of the culture, not culture from the language.

So, in order for a gender difference to come about in every day life, that gender needs to be important to the group. When men and women have similar roles and are treated equally, the gender differences fade from the language.

So, start with highly different gender roles and responsibilities. When men and women have different cultural roles, their words will be different. When gay men have special positions in culture, the language will have special words for them. (Likewise, for lesbian women and transgender people.) When a culture has a highly complex religious interactions with fantasy people, the language will have words for those "unreal" people. When a culture commonly consults the spirits of the dead for business / war decisions, their advice will be given that gender. Consider how a group of people will come together and talk over a message from one of the other genders. They will have to use the proper gender forms of words.

You list "real" and "alive". It is far more likely that those attributes will be assumed. You might want to have "unreal" or "dream" people as those are likely to be given special considerations in a culture. (There are cultures that give special credence to dreams. See Matthew 2:13)

It is also important that reading / writing is very limited. A language that gets written down tends to slow down changing. For example, English prior to the Kings James Bible changed rapidly. Afterwards, because of the wide spread "standard" for the language, it changed far more slowly.

Comment: In this role men and women do have different roles. Men have the main job of building things with wood and stone, while women have the the main job of making clothing, blankets, baskets,  and are the only ones able to create potions from their milk. Both men and women hunt because it's custom for the wife and the husband to hunt together for the children and for their brother's and their wifes. I forgot to say that 
not-real/unknown is also a gender.

Comment: "When men and women have similar roles and are treated equally, the gender differences fade from the language." - Yeah, no. Chinese is essentially grammatically genderless, and anyone arguing that men and women were treated equally until very recently, long after the language developed, is amazingly ignorant of history. Meanwhile, Switzerland is considered the top country in gender equality, and they speak Italian, German, French, and Romansh, all which have grammatical gender. The presence or absence of gender in the language says *nothing* about its culture.

Comment: @KeithMorrison: valid point, but the question is specifically about the 1st person pronoun. We're not talking about the gender of chairs (which is a thing in the swiss languages), but the gender of people.

Comment: @MSalters The point holds for the Chinese languages though. However I'd like to note that most things are never absolutely true or false. The problem is cultures change over time and language change over time and quite often the two are not in sync

Comment: I think the main reason why first-person pronouns are usually gender-neutral, as opposed to third-person pronouns, is because the gender of the person speaking is usually obvious in oral language. For first-person pronouns to be gendered, you'd need situations in which the gender of the speaker might be hidden.

Comment: @KeithMorrison You are arguing with a strawman. The implication is that in-language gender distinction requires gender to be relevant (not equal), NOT that the *lack* of gender distinction in language implies fair gender roles. (=> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent).

Comment: @radioflash, the original quote "When men and women have similar roles and are treated equally, the gender differences fade from the language" directly connects the two issues, so not strawman at all.

Comment: @KeithMorrison - "When A, then B" does *not* imply that "Since B, then A".  There could also be a "When C, then B" which is the relevant one.  To put it in a simple example: "When I get a paycheck, then I have money." doesn't imply "Because I have money, therefore I got a paycheck" - I could have won the lottery instead.

Comment: "*Both men and women hunt because it's custom for the wife and the husband to hunt together for the children*".  Who takes care of the children (especially if no grandparents around) and the house?  Also, if you've ever been around pregnant women -- especially after the fourth month -- you'd know that's not a very good idea.   "*and for their brother's and their wifes[sic].*"  Why aren't the brothers and their wives out hunting, too?

Comment: _in order for a gender difference to come about in every day life, that gender needs to be important to the group._ - I would also add that this is more likely to come about if gender is often not obvious (either in direct communication or over the phone or in written communication).

Answer (score 3):

**Use honorifics?**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_honorifics

Wikipedia is more thorough but this site has cute chibi.
https://www.japanesepod101.com/blog/2016/07/11/japanese-honorifics-guide-san-kun-chan-sama-and-more/

> Senpai (せんぱい), the equivalent of “senior.” This is used for classmates
> in higher grades and all people with more experience than yourself
> either at work, club, or in any kind of group.

You could use honorifics as they use in Japanese.  A nice thing about these is it is easy to graft them onto other languages - for example anime subtitles sometimes keep them with the English translation.  I might refer to L.Dutch-senpai and JBH-san and people would know what I meant.

Also it is clear where these terms came from: they were borrowed by weebs who love things Japanese.  So too in your world - a different language had these terms and they have been adopted into the language of the protagonists.  They can refer to the qualifying adjectives you mention and more.

I do insist that you have a 6th: if you have real you must have unreal.  Real is used mostly for emphasis - like "he is the real thing!".  Unreal should be a modification of real and rarely used.  It provokes a question - "why do you call him unreal"?   The original language these came from was more serious about using "real" and very serious about "unreal".

Answer (score 0):

So in many languages, there is a gender component.  Usually it is Male, Female, and Neuter.

These are in a variety of languages that evolved naturally and from different cultures.  Romance languages have genders, and so does German.  The linguistic roots of these languages are different.  Yet you still have the 3 genders.  The gender can be expressed as a separate word or a suffix to the word.

In your language you might want to look at existing languages and then simply subdivide the Neuter gender to reflect real, alive, and dead.

Comment: Yeah the real gender in this language is usually marked by not marking it with anything unless the word ends in with the sounds /aŋ/ or /aɱ/ because of changes through the years to not mix real with dead or alive.

Comment: @MathCookie It really is up to you since it's a made up language.  In German, you just have to know the gender of the word.  There are clues when someone is speaking or writing it down.  Die, Das, and Der indicate the gender in German.  In your language, just formalize the gender in the suffix of the word.

Comment: Actually, it's masculine not male, feminine not female, and neuter. To paraphrase the words of a Roman grammarian who lived 1600 years ago, words are called masculine not because they beget offspring or refer to male beings, but because they require the same forms of pronouns and adjectives as the word "he"; feminine words do not give birth to offspring, but rather they just require the same forms of pronouns and adjectives as the word "she". For example, consider the French words for "felony" and "misdemeanor": one is masculine and one is feminine, but none of them is either male or female.

Comment: If by separate "words" u do not mean article then maybe add it to u answer as well

Comment: I think this answer is misleading. The first paragraph suggests the three gender system with feminine/masculine/neuter is is more common than other systems. While this IS common in Indo-European languages, many of them make only a m/f distinction, some have non-sex-related genders and lack gender. Outside Indo-European, Arabic use a m/f system, Bantu languages have a butt-load of genders not relating to sex, etc etc. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_type_of_grammatical_genders#Masculine,_feminine,_and_neuter

Comment: Also, you seem to suggest that the genders in German and Latin somehow developed independently. This is not just misleading but wrong. The linguistic roots, as you put it, of these languages are THE SAME as they both have developed from an Indo-European language, which linguists agree had grammatical gender to start with. As for your final paragraph, as the various gender systems in circulation suggest, there is no reason to believe that the m/f genders are somehow more basic than others and should come first when making up languages. Unless you are making your own European language, that is.

Comment: @PaulTIKI The OP aksks about how the genders would come into existence - i.e. about that etymology. If you look into existing languages, you will find examples that are very close to the description - not to go too far, e.g. Polish has masculine personal, masc. animate, masc. inanimate, feminine, neutrum.

Comment: Is it really true that it is usually masculine, feminine, and neuter? Or is that simply Indo-European bias?

Answer (score 0):

Pratically any neo-latin language has third person different pronouns for male and female. English has a pronoun for things (it), neo latin languages don't have a pronoun for things.

If your problem is a first person gendered pronoun and the domain is a fantasy world with 5 genders (male, female, real, not-real/unknown, alive, and dead) my best bet is such kind of pronoun is necessary because a person "gender" is not detectable only by listen his/her/its name. In modern western languages gendered first person pronouns are not necessary because person' voice and first names make the job. Eg: male John, feminine Jane, Sian, Johannah.

Other explanation (into a magical world): some one makes use of seance to connect to spirits by means of a medium (human agent) in such case the spirit uses a gendered pronoun to indicate what /he/she/it is.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [Zeiss Icon answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/203370/232), I think the answer is simply "To provide the interlocutor the gender of the speaker". This can happen if this people have an androginous phisonomy / garments / communication.
You can see this nowadays on the internet, with some people including their pronoun in their email signatures or account profiles. Since the communication is in written form, this extra cue is needed in order to [convey the gender](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PronounTrouble).

I would expect that on this language pronouns are gendered on all persons. So to a phrase "I-masculine welcome you-feminine to my house" would receive a reply such as "I-feminine thank you-masculine for welcoming me into your house".

It's also possible, albeit rare, that someone uses the wrong pronoun to express their support to another group. E.g. "I-feminine consider very worrying the number of women that have been murdered in the last months" said by a man. Here, the function of the feminine pronoun is to show solidarity, that right now he feels himself part of the women, he names himself another woman.

In contrast, people names are probably used interchangeably for men and women, without being "assigned" to one of them, as the gender in the accompanying words would already convey that, so a name would flow to both boys and girls.

Answer (score 0):

> How could gender on 1st person pronouns come into existence?

I see there are lots of interesting answers on how this may evolve 'naturally' due to a variety of factors. But so far nobody seems to have caught on to this part of the question:

> I've been working on a language where every noun is required to state what gender it is.

I may be misinterpreting this, but it seems that you're saying that the language itself is very strongly gendered, to the point where everyone would be confused by the existence of nouns without any gender signifier. Non-personal pronouns already have gender signifiers, so if it is an important part of the language I suspect that the rule would either already apply to personal pronouns or some movement of rational linguists might propose that such a thing be adopted.

It seems that in many real-world cases the non-gendered personal pronoun predates the gendering of nouns. Even in heavily gender-tagged languages the personal pronoun remains ungendered. Maybe it's because it's simply easier to assume that the person you are talking to can figure it out for themselves (broadly true for speech, less so for writing), or because people tend to use the personal pronoun to reference their internal identity which needs no clarification of gender *to themselves,* or maybe because it's just easier to say "I" than "I(masculine, living, real)" or something.

But of course our rational linguists are purists who care not for how complex the language must become in order to satisfy their quest for perfectly rational self-expression. Not only have they mandated gendered personal pronouns for all polite society, but next week they're going to tackle the sheer inadequacy of pronouns to truly convey the full detail of one(neutral, hypothetical, indeterminate, nonspecific, singular)'s true self. Those baroque little pronouns will be replaced by the far more accurate language of complete self-description.

We expect the introduction to next week's meeting of the Council for Rational Language to last no more than three days. Per member.

Answer (score 0):

**Already Exists in the form of Illeism**

Illeism is the practice of referring to yourself in the third person. This is especially prevalent in countries like China and Japan, especially during ancient times. Your self-referral not can tell both your gender and your social station, and further can refer to your relation to the person you are talking about.